# How to move posts from blogging engine to another

Tags: rss, blogs, atom-feed, opml

How one can move blog posts from blogging engine to another? Is there away to transfer posts between blog engines, blogs ... lets say from community server blog to blog engine blog vice versa? Can that be done by using OPML, rss, atom ..etc?

Comment: You didn't mention which engines you're referring to. I wrote my own for SimplePHPBlog to WordPress Converter.

Comment: I think you would be better asking this question on www.superuser.com. StackOverflow is specifically for programming questions. Superuser is more suited for general computing questions like thi.s

Comment: @Randolph I mentioned what engines I need community server<>blog-engine.
@Simon I don't think so .. this is not a general question it needs a programming effort. There is no out-of the box way to do that and I am seeking for the best way to use. I can write my custom code to import/export data between the different database, but I am wondering if there is any way using those protocols?

Comment: Looks like this is a one-off task to migrate a blog. If so, then just write something that works without being pretty, probably in a nice simple scripting language :)

Comment: Community server? That's a blog engine? For me, a blog engine is Wordpress, Serendipity, DotClear, etc.
If you mean to do a transfer between two servers running the same blog software, you should indicate it.

Comment: @PhiLho - couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ... I found this standerd "Blogml" which could be used and I found a converters for transfering blog posts between applications [at CodePlex](http://blogml.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 1):

The Data Liberation Front has converters: http://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/

Converts between WordPress, Blogger, MovableType, and LiveJournal.

Sometimes blogging software has an importer and exporter for one of these formats, so you could use one of them as an intermediate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export/Import functionalities, if you're using a wordpress enabled blog.